# Another basic short exact sequence problem

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

In the following commutative diagram of R-modules, all of the rows and columns are exact. Prove that $K$ is isomorphic to $L$.

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc} &&&&&&&&0 &&\\ 
&&&&&&&&\downarrow &&\\ &&&&&& 0 & & L &&\\ &&&&&& \downarrow && \downarrow &&\\ &&&& M^{\prime\prime} & \rightarrow& N^{\prime\prime} & \rightarrow & P^{\prime\prime} & \rightarrow& 0\\ &&&& \downarrow &  &  \downarrow   &&  \downarrow &&\\ && 0 & \rightarrow & M & \rightarrow & N & \rightarrow & P & \rightarrow & 0\\ &&&& \downarrow  &  &  \downarrow   &&  \downarrow &&\\ 0 & \rightarrow  &  K & \rightarrow  & M^\prime & \rightarrow  &  N^\prime& \rightarrow  & P^\prime & \rightarrow  & 0\\ &&&& \downarrow  &  &  \downarrow   &&  \downarrow &&\\ 
&&&& 0 &  & 0   && 0 && \end{array}

Again I have no idea how to do, it seems so complicated, please helps.

Comment: Hah, I wish I could tell you why right away :) Rather than diagram chasing, I bet it's an application of a diagram lemma you learned recently. Do you have any such lemmas on hand?

Comment: snake lemma!! Let me think about it:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT** The snake lemma tells us that there is an exact sequence $$0 \to L \to M^\prime.$$

**HINT 2** Kernels of $R$-modules have a universal property.

*Added:* The universal property of a kernel is this. A kernel of a morphism $f:M \to N$ is a morphism $i:K \to M$ such that $f \circ i = 0$ and such that is universal with respect to this property, meaning that if $i^\prime:K^\prime \to M$ is any other morphism with $f \circ i^\prime = 0$, then there exists a unique morphism $u:K^\prime \to K$  such that $i^\prime = i \circ u$.

By standard category theoretic considerations, the universal property implies that any two kernels are uniquely isomorphic. For more on this, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28category_theory%29) on kernels.

Comment: do you mind explain what is meant by universal property? I still don't quite get it...

Comment: @Excelsior: Sure, I've added an explanation.

Comment: If you want to apply the universal property of the kernel, don't you need to say that $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M' \rightarrow N'$ is exact (which it is)?